# How to load multiple pics into a single imageview in android

Tags: android, picasso

I am working on an instant chat messenger .I want to create new groups now. While creating groups i am getting an array of thumbnail URLS of the members of the group.I want to display the multiple images in an imageview using Picasso as facebook messenger do.Screenshot is given below:

[image: Groups picture]

As we can see in the screenshot ,image view contain the pic of members of all the group.Can anybody tell me how can i load multiple pics into single image view using picasso or by any other library ?

Comment: I don't think so it is possible in one `ImageView`, however you can do it in one `layout` or in `canvas` and can give shape of `canvas` or `layout`

Comment: Can you please explain in detail ?In the screenshot,it is displaying multiple images in a single circular image view .I want to achieve the same .

Comment: i think not possible that. But you can make on layout Like frame layout and put imageviews and set images as like you say.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this! Just Try !

```
public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 0, 0, null);
    return bmOverlay; }
```

Hopefully it will help you !